# Backbone Views within Views within Views - why does this.$el.html('insert some content here') do nothing?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

This is going to be quite a complex one, so I'll keep adding to it as I go along.

My app is structured out of two primary types of Views - a standard View and a Region (a special type of View solely intended to contain other views. My root app view is a region, consisting of various other regions that I can then 'plug' views into as needed.

All of my views that sit in the main app regions (header, footer, modals etc.) all work absolutely fine. Today I tried creating some sub regions, within other views and I've hit a snag. For some reason, when I call `this.$el.html()` on the region to pass in the output of the region's assigned view nothing happens. I can step through the code and the view is rendering within itself nicely, and I can see the markup by looking at the object model in the console. However it never actually joins up to the page and all I see is the markup that represents the region wrapper.

Here's some code - hopefully it'll make some sense, this goes down quite a few levels though...

Firstly my base classes for views and regions...

```
define(['backbone', 'helpers/cookie-manager'],
    function (Backbone, CookieManager) {

        var spinner = "<img src='/content/images/global/ajax-loader.png' alt='loading...' />";        

        var ministryView = Backbone.View.extend({

            name: 'Unnamed View',
            sectionName: 'No section specified',

            stateRequired: false,

            template: undefined,

            bindings: [],

            initialize: function (options) {
                this.options = options || {};
                Backbone.View.prototype.initialize.call(this, options);
                if (this.options.name) {
                    this.name = this.options.name;
                }
                if (this.options.sectionName) {
                    this.sectionName = this.options.sectionName;
                }
                if (this.options.template) {
                    this.template = this.options.template;
                }
            },

            bindToModel: function (model, ev, callback, that) {
                if (that === undefined || that === null) {
                    throw "The value of 'that' needs the context of the extending class in order to operate correctly.";
                }
                model.bind(ev, callback, that);
                this.bindings.push({ model: model, ev: ev, callback: callback });
            },

            dispose: function () {
                this.unbindFromAllModels();   // Will unbind all events this view has bound to
                this.stopListening();
                this.unbind();                // This will unbind all listeners to events from this view. This is probably not necessary because this view will be garbage collected.
                this.remove();                // Uses the default Backbone.View.remove() method which removes this.el from the DOM and removes DOM events.
                this.undelegateEvents();
            },

            render: function () {
                this.trigger('rendered');
                return this;
            },

            resetStyleState: function(condition) {
            },

            trash: function () {
                this.dispose();
            },

            unbindFromAllModels: function () {
                _.each(this.bindings, function (binding) {
                    binding.model.unbind(binding.ev, binding.callback);
                });
                this.bindings = [];
            }
        });

        var ministryRegion = ministryView.extend({

            name: 'Unnamed Region',

            currentView: undefined,

            initialize: function (options) {
                this.options = options || {};
                ministryView.prototype.initialize.call(this, options);
                if (this.options.currentView) {
                    this.currentView = this.options.currentView;
                }
                _.bindAll(this, 'placeRenderedView');
                _.bindAll(this, 'showRendering');
            },

            placeRenderedView: function () {
                this.$el.html(this.currentView.$el);
                this.currentView.delegateEvents();

                if (this.currentView.postRender !== undefined && this.currentView.postRender !== null) {
                    this.currentView.postRender();
                }
            },

            renderView: function (view) {
                if (view) {
                    if (this.currentView) {
                        this.currentView.trash();
                    }

                    this.currentView = view;
                }

                this.currentView.bind('rendering', this.showRendering);
                this.currentView.bind('rendered', this.placeRenderedView);
                this.currentView.render();
            },

            showRendering: function () {
                this.$el.html(spinner);
            },

            trash: function(disposeRegion) {
                this.currentView.trash();

                if (disposeRegion !== undefined && disposeRegion !== null && disposeRegion !== false) {
                    this.dispose();
                }
            }
        });


        return {
            View: ministryView,
            Region: ministryRegion
        };
    });
```

Now the view that loads into the app, that contains the region that I want to load the view into (`mealPlansRegion`)...

```
define(['ministry', 'jquery', 'views/v-header', 'models/m-ns', 'views/components/components', 'text!templates/hub/member-home.html'],
    function (Ministry, $, Header, Models, Components, TemplateSource) {    
        var memberHomeView = Ministry.SecureView.extend({

            name: 'Member Home',
            sectionName: 'Hub',

            mealPlansRegion: undefined,

            template: Handlebars.compile(TemplateSource),

            headerView: new Header({ text: 'Kitchen Hub', swatch: 'a' }),

            initialize: function (options) {
                Ministry.SecureView.prototype.initialize.call(this, options);
            },

            // Need to override the normal secured view implementation.
            render: function () {
                this.$el.html(this.template(this));
                this.mealPlansRegion = new Ministry.Region({ el: '.meal-plans-container' });
                this.mealPlansRegion.renderView(new Components.MealPlansList({ collection: new Models.MealPlan.OwnedCollection({ username: App.session.username() }) }));
                this.trigger('rendered');
                return this;
            },

            postRender: function () {
                if (!this.isSecured()) {
                    App.router.navigate('/');
                    App.renderHome(false);
                }
            }
        });

        return memberHomeView;
    });
```

... and it's template ...

```
<section class="meal-plans-container">
</section>
```

... just contains a placeholder at the moment for the region. Eventually, the intention is to have several of these here with interchangeable content. Finally, here's the view I'm trying to load in...

```
define(['ministry', 'jquery', 'models/m-meal-plan', 'text!templates/components/meal-plans-list.html'],
    function(Ministry, $, MealPlan, TemplateSource) {
        var mealPlansListView = Ministry.SecureView.extend({

            name: 'Meal Plans List Component',

            template: Handlebars.compile(TemplateSource),

            render: function () {
                var that = this;

                if (this.isSecured()) {
                    this.collection.on('fetching', function () {
                        that.trigger('rendering');
                    });

                    this.collection.fetch({
                        success: function() {
                            that.bindData();
                            that.trigger('rendered');
                        },
                        error: function(model, xhr) {
                            that.$el.html('Unable to fetch meal plan data');
                            if (console !== undefined && console !== null) {
                                console.log('Fetch Meal Plan failed: ' + xhr.responseText);
                            }
                            that.trigger('rendered');
                        }
                    });
                } else {
                    this.applySecureLoginPrompt();
                }

                return this;
            },

            bindData: function () {
                this.$el.html(this.template({ plans: this.collection.toJSON() }));
            }
        });

        return mealPlansListView;
    });
```

and it's template...

```
<ul id="mealPlansList" class="swatch-listview-b">
    <li class="listview-header">Meal Plans</li>
    {{#each plans}}
    <li><span class="meal-plan-id-holder hidden">{{id}}</span>{{name}}</li>
    {{/each}}
</ul>
```

for this particular view, this part of the common region code fails...

```
        placeRenderedView: function () {
            this.$el.html(this.currentView.$el);
            this.currentView.delegateEvents();

            if (this.currentView.postRender !== undefined && this.currentView.postRender !== null) {
                this.currentView.postRender();
            }
        },
```

... and the `this.$el.html(this.currentView.$el);` line doesn't do anything at all.

If I can provide anything else to help, please let me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to sort this out, with a little help from this article here - [Backbone View Nesting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7654543/backbone-view-nesting?rq=1)

I rewrote the `memberHomeView` class and moved the region instantiation from the `render` to the `postRender` function. This then ensured that the template rendering had been completed, allowing the region to then instantiate correctly (It comes back to me now that this is why I created the `postRender` method in the first place.

Here's the altered function...

```
define(['ministry', 'jquery', 'views/v-header', 'models/m-ns', 'views/components/components', 'text!templates/hub/member-home.html'],
    function (Ministry, $, Header, Models, Components, TemplateSource) {    
        var memberHomeView = Ministry.SecureView.extend({

            name: 'Member Home',
            sectionName: 'Hub',

            mealPlansRegion: undefined,

            template: Handlebars.compile(TemplateSource),

            headerView: new Header({ text: 'Kitchen Hub', swatch: 'a' }),

            initialize: function (options) {
                Ministry.SecureView.prototype.initialize.call(this, options);
            },

            // Need to override the normal secured view implementation.
            render: function () {
                this.$el.html(this.template(this));
                this.trigger('rendered');
                return this;
            },

            postRender: function () {
                if (!this.isSecured()) {
                    SiansPlanApp.router.navigate('/');
                    SiansPlanApp.renderHome(false);
                } else {
                    // MOVED THE REGION INSTANTIATION HERE
                    this.mealPlansRegion = new Ministry.Region({ el: '.meal-plans-container' });
                    this.mealPlansRegion.renderView(new Components.MealPlansList({ collection: new Models.MealPlan.OwnedCollection({ username: SiansPlanApp.session.username() }) }));
                }
            }
        });

        return memberHomeView;
    });
```

In Simple terms....

---

***If attaching to external markup, ensure that markup has rendered BEFORE you try to add a sub-view or region that uses it, else you may cry.***

---